# Choose what event to listen

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have this code:

```
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    findxy('move', e)
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
    findxy('down', e)
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
    findxy('up', e)
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
    findxy('out', e)
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("dblclick", function (e) {
    findxy('zoom', e);
}, false);
```

I want when the user double clicks on the canvas to prevent from listening the other events and execute only the code in the last listener. When the code in the event(dblclick) it is finished I want to listen again for the other events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a flag that tells `mousedown`, `mouseup`, `mousedown`, `mouseup` not to run their code until `dblClick` has fired.

The example code below uses a flag named `deactivateEvents` to tell the other mouse events not to run their code until `dblClick` has run.

When the user triggers `dblClick`, the dblClick code is executed and then the `deactivateEvents` flag is cleared so the other mouse events are freed to run their code.

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

// Flag: When ==true, the mouse move,down,up,out events
//       will be triggered, but won't run their code.
var deactivateEvents=true;

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  // only run this event's code if not deactivated
  if(deactivateEvents){return;}
  //
  findxy('move', e)
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
  // only run this event's code if not deactivated
  if(deactivateEvents){return;}
  //
  findxy('down', e)
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
  // only run this event's code if not deactivated
  if(deactivateEvents){return;}
  //
  findxy('up', e)
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
  // only run this event's code if not deactivated
  if(deactivateEvents){return;}
  //
  findxy('out', e)
}, false);
canvas.addEventListener("dblclick", function (e) {
  findxy('zoom', e);
  deactivateEvents=false;
}, false);

var $events=$('#events');
var $moves=$('#moves');
var moveCount=0;

function findxy(eType,e){
  // just testing...removeable
  if(eType=='move'){
    moveCount++;
    $moves.text(moveCount);
  }else{
    $events.text($events.text()+','+eType);
  }
  // do your findxy code
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
.inlineMe{display:inline-block;border:1px solid blue;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Canvas == red.<br>Mouse events code prevented until double-click in canvas.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=100></canvas>
<div class='inlineMe'>
  Move count:&nbsp;<span id='moves'>0</span>
  <br><textarea id='events' rows=19></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Remove Event Listener

In case you want to follow down your original approach, you could use:

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

```
canvas.removeEventListener()
```

inside your respective logic. But imho this way you will make your code harder to maintain or test.

### Event Delegation

Thus, I would suggest a completely different approach. It is called Event Delegationm you are able to save quite some resources and seriously safe on processing power that the browser needs when only listening to one event for your entire Web page.

I explained it here:

http://meshfields.de/event-delegation-in-javascript/

Comment: I see what you suggest and it is interesting I will check it

Comment: As far as concerned the efficiency of the two approaches you are right. But there is still the initial question,how I will prevent to listen other events if a specific event is fired? Then also I want to be able to listen again from the other events

Comment: I see - I add this to my answer https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener